# OpenVPN session ID for --client-connect and --client-disconnect (unpredictable execution order)

Tags: openvpn

I have an issue where:

1. Client A connects (--client-connect)
2. Client A connects again for some reason, maybe it crashed, maybe something else unexpected happened, who knows (--client-connect)
3. Client A original connection times out (--client-disconnect)

My script then notifies that a client disconnected, when in reality, it is the original session that disconnected but there is still an active session now.

I am familiar with explicit-exit-notify, but this is specifically for situations where the client did not notify of a disconnect.

Is there any kind of environment variable or something to identify which session disconnected? - this way I can say ah, it's the first session that's disconnected, the second session is still fine.

If not, any other solution/ENV var to correctly identify the session?

Comment: If you are interested only if the client has an active session, why not count the connects and the disconnects? So if number_of_connects - number_of_disconnects > 0 (for that particular client), then there is an active session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. When a client disconnects, the date in the ENV variable is actually of the time the connection started, not when it disconnected. It is up to you to calculate the disconnect time by adding the duration seconds.

I ended up with code like this to find the connection and fill in the missing details as well as the disconnect time (ruby):

```
case script_type
when 'client-connect'
  c = create!({ common_name:, starts_at:, time_unix: }.merge(v))
when 'client-disconnect'
  c = where(common_name:, time_unix:).first    
  c.bytes_received = v['bytes_received'].to_i
  c.bytes_sent = v['bytes_sent'].to_i
  c.time_duration = v['time_duration'].to_i
  c.ends_at = c.starts_at + c.time_duration.seconds
end
```